# How do I pass function variables by reference in C++/CLI?

Tags: c++-cli, visual-c++

How do you define `ref` in C++/CLI?

In C#, we can write:

```
public override void myfunction(TokenStream tokenStream, ref string outliningKey,
   ref OutliningNodeAction tokenAction);
```

So in C++/CLI, I tried to write:

```
public:virtual void myfunction(TokenStream ^ tokenStream,
   ref String ^ outliningKey, ref OutliningNodeAction  tokenAction)override
```

I want to define `String ^ outliningKey` AND `OutliningNodeAction tokenAction` to **`ref`**
in C++/CLI, but we don't have any **`ref`** keyword in C++/CLI.

Can anyone help me to define myfunction Variable to ref mod?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this syntax:

```
 public: virtual void myfunction(String ^% outliningKey) { .... }
```